# Using minors to determine type of extrema

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I've found [this page](http://statmath.wu.ac.at/~leydold/MOK/HTML/node60.html#def%3aHauptminor) for calculating the minors (Hauptminoren) of the Hessian matrix to determine which of the critical points of the matrix correspond to a maximum, a minimum or a saddle point. They say the matrix is positive definite if all $|q_A| > 0$ and negative if $|q_A|(-1)^k>0$, and a saddle point if otherwise. But what happens if one of $|q_A|$ is zero? No conclusion possible?

Comment: Possibly a related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44941/extrema-of-f-mathbbrn-rightarrow-mathbbr

Comment: Yeah, I'd say related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical example is the function

$$F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} : (x,y) \mapsto x^4+y^4$$

which has a minimum at $(0,0)$ but the Hessian matrix is the zero matrix in that point.

On the other hand,

$$F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} : (x,y) \mapsto x^3+y^3$$

also has Hessian matrix equal to the zero matrix in $(0,0)$, but this time you don't have a minimum or maximum.

So, the Hessian alone doesn't allow you to conclude in these cases.